# Global File Referencing

Tags: php, html, url, structured-data

My basic file structure something like:

```
domain.com/
        home.php
        images/
                global/
                        nav/
                            nav-img.jpg
        includes/
                menu.php
        fruit/
                apples/
                        red/
                            gala/
                                gala.php
```

I want to create a global path establishing my web root that I can reference on the fly in each page wherever it resides. I'm trying to figure out how to use [for example] **define(ROOT)**, and how to call it from an individual page.

Knowing that all pages use [menu.php], my obstacle is, for example:

From the gala.php page  - when I click on [home], it looks for:

```
/fruit/apples/red/gala/home.php
```

But that doesn't exist.

*Also, I'm **trying to avoid** these [2] things IF POSSIBLE:*

1. Using html file references in **gala.php** like this: 
   ../../../../includes/menu.php   [to find the correct global include]
2. And avoid using link references in **menu.php** like this: 
   /images/global/nav/nav-img.jpg

**

## Update

**

1. SOLVED

Like others have posted, I ended up using:

```
define('ROOT',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']); 
define('INCLUDES',ROOT.'/path/to/includes/folder/');
```

which worked well when I call it from the html with:

```
include(INCLUDES.'menu.php');  // or any file
```

This was great because I can find my includes no matter where they're called from... and this was easy once I figured out how to use it.

**

## Remaining Problem

**

[for #2 above] The only remaining problem is that all my html links in the includes are broken where the include is called from a level other than from ROOT.

I found a workaround is to just use absolute paths like:

```
href="/images/global/nav/nav-img.jpg"
```

**Is there a way I can create a DOCUMENT_ROOT type of file reference for image locations so my includes will always find them?**

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you could use $_SERVER information found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) to assign a $server_root variable or a $prefix variable and base everything off of that.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is using this code in your (X)HTML:

<base href="my-root">

Comment: Yea I just found `<base>` thx paul. But that would break every other link on the page.

Comment: Thx for that idea too, tho `$_SERVER` looks like it's deprecated.